# How to get java 1.6 applet working on mac os x

Tags: java, applet, java-6

anyone got java 1.6 applet working on mac os x ?
check it on gemal.dk/browserspy/java.html 
I got Java using object and applet tag  1.5.0_16 (1.5.0_16-133) from Apple Inc.
and you ?

on windows and linux 1.6 working gracefully :S

Comment: usefulness of your answers is below the 0
google was already tested 
the problem is that java 1.6 plugin is 64bit only and Safari is 32bit only so you can't get java1.6 applets in safari 
don't know why apple said so ...

Comment: oh and to be clear I have leopard with an intel mac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with OSX itself that didn't support 1.6 on applets now everything is updated and works on 10.6.6 at least
I wrote it here so somebody don't confuse this problem with another.

Answer (score 3):

On Leopard, open `/Applications/Utilities/Java/Java Preferences.app`, and select Java 6 as the default for your applets. This won't work, of course, if you don't have an Intel Mac running Leopard (at least, I think it requires Leopard... perhaps there's an installer for Tiger). In either event, not reliable if you need to deploy 1.6-based applets to users, but works tickety-boo for your own surfing.

Answer (score 0):

There should be an installed Java JRE picker... had a similar road block, give it a peak.